# Slick2d Main Program issues

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

Error Code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
at bossRush.MainGame.main(MainGame.java:41)
```

Main code:

```java
package bossRush;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class MainGame extends StateBasedGame {
public static final String name = "Boss Rush";
public static final int menu = 0;
public static final int map = 1;
//public static final int play = 2;
//public static final int save = 3;
//public static final int load = 4;
//public static final int DIX = 5;

public MainGame(String name) {
    super(name);
    this.addState(new Menu(menu));
    this.addState(new Map(map));
    //this.addState(new Play(play));
    //this.addState(new Save(save));
    //this.addState(new Save(load));
    //this.addState(new Menu(DIX));
}


public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    this.getState(menu);
    this.getState(map);
    //this.getState(play);
    //this.getState(save);
    //this.getState(load);
    //this.getState(DIX);   
    this.enterState(menu);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    AppGameContainer appgc;
       try{
          appgc = new AppGameContainer(new MainGame(name));
          appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 640, false);
          appgc.start();
       }catch(SlickException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
}

}
```

finally a sample of the states:

```
package bossRush;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState{
public static int ID;

public Menu(int id){
    ID = id;
}

public void init(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1)throws SlickException {


}

public void render(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, Graphics arg2)throws SlickException {

}

public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2)throws SlickException {

}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

}
```

I have no idea what is causing the error, if you have a suggestion please let me know. If it has something to do with what needs to be refferenced, slick.jar, lwjgl.jar, jinput.jar.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the library files for lwjgl. If Windows it will be a .dll file and if Linux it will be a .so file.

Check the lwjgl documentation to find out what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

OMG i downloaded the wrong lwjgl.
i had to re-download to get the correct lwjgl to get the proper natives.
to anyone who does this, you must NOT download the "lwjgl source" file, just the "lwjgl" file.